# HTML PHP: Why do two identical select elements produce different HTML displays?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Could someone kindly help out with this rather basic issue: In a simple HTML form (functionally all good) two select elements are included.
Code:

```
<select id="dept" name="dept" required>
    <?php
        foreach($stddept as $item0) {           
            echo "<option value='$item0'";
            if ($_POST['dept'] == $item0) echo 'selected="selected"';
            echo ">$item0</option>";
        }   
    ?>                  
</select>                   
<br><br>
<select id="lev" name="lev" required>
    <?php
        foreach($stdlev as $item1) {            
            echo "<option value='$item1'";
            if ($_POST['lev'] == $item1) echo selected="selected"';                     
            echo ">$item1</option>";
        } 
    ?>  
</select>
<input type='submit' id='submituser' name='submituser' value='Submit'>`
```

These two drop-down boxes behave differently in that only the second one honours the 'required' attribute. The first one can be submitted blank, which is obviously not right.

They also appear differently (see image) in that the first displays the first option in the list (from MySQL DB) but the second displays a blank. I have checked everything I could to see what else could cause the difference - without any joy.

[image: screenshot of select boxes]

Does anyone know what I am missing here? Thank you.

Comment: The first thing you are missing is the opportunity for indenting your code correctly. Those who are reading it here will thank you a lot if you do so. And it will be better to you too.

Comment: I think I have found the solution: Apparently HTML5 needs a blank option in the select tag to make it work, eg: `code` <option value=''>$item1</option> `code`  Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jquery/javascript by getting the id of the first selected value and then select the result for the second box based on that id.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the code ( as it is shown ) is that you are incorrectly echoing the option in the second dropdown - it is missing quotes. You can streamline the code somewhat like this:

```
<select id="dept" name="dept" required='required'>
    <?php
        foreach($stddept as $item0){
            $selected=$_POST['dept'] == $item0 ? " selected='selected'" : "";
            echo "<option value='$item0'{$selected}>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select id="lev" name="lev" required='required'>
    <?php
        foreach($stdlev  as $item1){
            $selected=$_POST['lev'] == $item1 ? " selected='selected'" : "";
            echo "<option value='$item1'{$selected}>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
<input type='submit' id='submituser' name='submituser' value='Submit'>
```

Comment: Tx RamRaider.  I ran both sets of script simultaneously on the page. What is interesting is that the first select in your suggested mod still does not honour the 'required' part. Curious.